# Exception while reading contact list

Tags: android, android-contacts

Hi guys i'm getting the following Exception while readying contact list.

```
04-13 13:51:15.210: E/AndroidRuntime(7343): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
```

Here is my getContact function

```
 public static ContactList getContactList(Context context){
    ContactList contactList = new ContactList(RequestStatus.CONTACT_LIST);
    Cursor people =     context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    while(people.moveToNext()) {
       int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
       String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
       int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);
       String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);  
       contactList.addContact(new Contact(contact,number));
    }
    people.close();
    return contactList;
}
```

The exception is being thrown at following line.

```
String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: "col -1 failed" - looks like people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME) returned -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below method to get a list of contacts::

```
private ContactList getDetails(){
    ContactList contactList = new ContactList(RequestStatus.CONTACT_LIST);
    Uri uri = contactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
    String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
    Cursor names = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    int indexName = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    names.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String name   = names.getString(indexName);
        Log.e("Name new:", name);
        String number = names.getString(indexNumber);
        Log.e("Number new:","::"+number);
        contactList.addContact(new Contact(name,number));
    } while (names.moveToNext());
    return contactList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move to first column before, to make sure that the cursor is on valid index:

```
if (people.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
       int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
       String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
       int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);
       String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);  
       contactList.addContact(new Contact(contact,number));
    }while(people.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you about exception. This was just about I not rturning the row which your required. either you requesting for invalid column

Answer (score 0):

use

```
public static void getContactNumbers(Context context) {
    String contactNumber = null;
    int contactNumberType = Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;
    String nameOfContact = null;
    if (ApplicationConstants.phoneContacts.size() <= 0) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                nameOfContact = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor phones = cr
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                    null);

                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        contactNumber = phones.getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                        contactNumberType = phones.getInt(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                        Log.i(TAG, "...Contact Name ...." + nameOfContact
                                + "...contact Number..." + contactNumber);

                    }
                    phones.close();
                }

            }
        }// end of contact name cursor
        cur.close();

    }
}
```

thats what help for me when I was the same problem

[found it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107056/getting-all-phone-book-contact-details-into-an-array-in-android/6107324#6107324)